# Removing lines that contain a specific number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I was wondering if there was a way to remove lines from a file that contain a specific number (or numbers).

I know there's a way to remove lines that contain a specific string, but I want to remove lines that contain a specific number.

Say I have a text file that contains data such as:

```
201 740 0
202 288 4
202 294 3
202 330 5
202 358 1
202 259 0
```

and I want to remove the lines that contain the number 0, **just 0 (not 201, 202, or any other number that has 0 in it).**

I want the example output to be:

```
201 740 0
202 259 0
```

How would I go about doing it?

I have tried the following:

```
with open('oldfile.txt') as infile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if '0':
            outfile.write(line)
```

but it still writes each line, and I only want the lines that have the number **0** by itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('oldfile.txt') as infile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if ' 0' in line:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Your logical expression is trying to see `if ' 0'`, which will evaluate to true.

What you need to check is if '0' is in the line, so `if ' 0' in line:`

Comment: I tried this and it was still outputting every line. Maybe it doesn't recognize the white space before ' 0'?

Comment: @andresc23 really? did you include `if ' 0' in line`? the `in line` part is what actually does the checks

Comment: Oops. I did not, thats my fault tho. I missed that part somehow. I fixed it though and it worked great and gave the intended output. Thank you!

Comment: This will produce the wrong output if data has leading zeroes : it would erroneously match a line like this : `202 030 5`

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
if line.strip().endswith(" 0"):
    pass
else:
    outfile.write(line)
```

to skip lines that end with "0" in `outfile`

Comment: I actually wanted just the lines that have "0" in them. But this is actually a great solution. Changed the if-statement to an if-not statement and it worked as intended. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
with open('text1.txt','r+') as f:
    f2 = [l for l in f if '0' in l.split()]

with open('text2.txt','w') as f: 
    f.write(''.join(f2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
if '0':
```

will always evaluates as `True`, because non empty strings evaluate as true. It's the same thing as doing `if 'hello':` or `if True:`.

What you want to do is parse your line and only compare the last field

Try this :

```py
with open('oldfile.txt') as infile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split(' ')
        if fields[-1] == '0':
            outfile.write(line)
```

`line.split(' ')` allows you to work on a list that looks like this :

```py
['201', '740', '0']
```

From there, it's easy to make sure the last field is `'0'`.

If you're looking for the value '0' in any fields, it's easy to do this as well :

```py
with open('oldfile.txt') as infile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split(' ')
        if '0' in fields:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most generic solution i come up with uses regex. Here is the solution.

```
import re

with open('oldfile.txt') as infile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    pattern = re.compile('\D0\D|\D0$|^0\D')
    for line in infile:
        if not pattern.search(line):
            outfile.write(line)
```